# ActiveRecord: Select max of limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to convert the following SQL query to ActiveRecord and it's melting my brain.

```
delete from table where id <= (
select max(id) from (
    select id from table order by id limit 0, 10));
```

Any ideas?

What I'm trying to do is limit the number of rows in the table. So, I want to delete anything that is less than the most recent 10 entries.

edit:
Found a solution by combining several of the below answers.

```
Temperature.where('id < ?', Temperature.order('id DESC').limit(10).pluck(:id).min).destroy_all
```

This leaves me with the latest 10 entries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your SQL, it looks like you want to delete the first 10 records from the table. I believe most of the answers so far will so that. Here are two additional alternatives:

**Based on MurifoX's version:**

```
Table.where(:id=>Table.order(:id).limit(10).pluck(:id)).destroy_all
```

This will effectively perform a WHERE id IN (...)

**Slightly shorter version:**

```
Table.order(:id).limit(10).destroy_all
```

This will simply grab the first 10 records and destroy

**EDIT:** To grab all but the most recent X number of records (10 for example), only way I can think of to do that at the moment is this:

```
 Table.order(:id).limit(Table.count - 10).destroy_all if Table.count > 10
```

In essence, grab the oldest records, leaving only the 10 most recent, and destroy them, assuming the table size is greater than 10. Maybe there's a cleaner way to do it, but that's the only way I can imagine doing this right now.

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is limit the number of rows in the table. So if there are 11,delete 1. 15 delete 5.

Answer (score 3):

```
model = Model.order(:id).limit(10).last

Model.where("id <= ?", model.id).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe this?

```
Model.destroy(Model.where('id <= ?', Model.order(:id).limit(10).pluck(:id).max))
```

Comment: its not a single object i think

Answer (score 0):

Should be

> YourAR.destroy(YouAR.order(:id).max(:id))

That's untested. The idea is you want to delete the array of IDs returned by something.  I don't know if you can do this all in a single query (without just exec'ing SQL).

Comment: Just want to point out, be careful with delete, as it won't trigger any callback. Destroy will however.